# NullnessChecker: how to disable only the Initialization checker?

Tags: java, checker-framework

I refer to the [nullness-example in the docs](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-example) (checker-framework version: `2.1.14`)

When I run the example as recommended to check [NullnessExampleWithWarnings.java](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/checker-framework-2.1.14/docs/examples/NullnessExampleWithWarnings.java):

```
javac -processor org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker docs/examples/NullnessExampleWithWarnings.java
```

I get the expected errors:

```
..\..\docs\examples\NullnessExampleWithWarnings.java:23: error: [assignment.type.incompatible] incompatible types in assignment.
        foo = bar;
              ^
  found   : @FBCBottom @Nullable String
  required: @UnknownInitialization @NonNull String
..\..\docs\examples\NullnessExampleWithWarnings.java:33: error: [argument.type.incompatible] incompatible types in argument.
        foo.add(quux);
                ^
  found   : @FBCBottom @Nullable String
  required: @Initialized @NonNull String
2 errors
```

Now I disable the [Initialization checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#initialization-checker): with `AsuppressWarnings=initialization`.

```
javac -processor org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker -AsuppressWarnings=initialization docs/examples/NullnessExampleWithWarnings.java
```

But this also disables the null-checks and the build does not report anymore errors.

How can I disable the [Initialization checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#initialization-checker), but keep the Null-checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sections [3.1](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checks) and [3.8](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#initialization-checker) of the [Checker Framework manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checks) suggest using `-AsuppressWarnings=uninitialized` rather than `-AsuppressWarnings=initialization`.  That works for your example.

The reason for that recommendation is an implementation detail of the Nullness and Initialization Checkers:  they are actually the same checker, rather than being two separate checkers that are aggregated together.